# Model Binding in Symfony

Tags: php, rest, symfony, model-view-controller

From few days I'm struggling with implementation of model binding mechanism known from ASP MVC into world of Symfony REST, but with no luck.

I encountered something similar - @ParamConverter, but from tries I made it looks like its not what I'm looking for.

My attempts ended at [Body Converter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/request_body_converter_listener.html). When I POSTed my form-data to desired route : `/api/posts` I received error about not existing route. debug:router gave me route different that i expected :  `/api/posts/{post}.{_format}`. It seems to me that Body converters want me to send data in json or xml, but i want to send form-data because of files. Solution what im looking for should work like this :

```
/**
* @ParamConverter("Post", class="BlogBundle:Post")
*/
public function postPostAction(Post $post)
{
    if($post->isValid())
    {
        $em->persist($post);
    }    
}
```

Do anyone can give some clues, or implementation how to make it work? Because i belive I'm not only one who want to achive such elegant way